# The animation of the first row DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, expression-blend

Maybe someone knows the answer to my question. How to make text color of the new added row in Datagrid brighter than other rows in the first 5 seconds, and then she again became the same as all the rows? 
If this is done through the animation, then tell me please how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Expression blend to create WPF animation.
It ll generate Xaml code which use the [StoryBoard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard(v=vs.110).aspx) xaml Tag.

You should have somthink like that code Snippet.

```
           <DataGrid.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="DataGrid.MouseLeave">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation To="Red" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(your new row here ???).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Duration="0:0:10"></ColorAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </DataGrid.Triggers>
```